# Error , Infeasible No value for uninitialized NumericValue object

Tags: python, linear-programming, solver, pyomo, glpk

I'm trying to optmize a problem of clients/facility allocation and I'm using pyomo to do so. I have the following problem that appear and cannot solve it even if I initialize all the values of Model.z to 0; the problems is still infeasible

```
from __future__ import division
import pyomo.environ as pyo
#from pyomo.environ import *
from pyomo.opt import SolverFactory
import sys
import numpy as np
import sys
import os

from time import perf_counter
from pulp import *
from pyomo.util.infeasible import log_infeasible_constraints

#print(sys.path)
opt = pyo.SolverFactory('glpk')
opt.options['threads'] =4


#import instance 
model = pyo.ConcreteModel()

# n is the number of facility related to J
# m is the number of clients related to I 
# t is the number of periods relatdd to T 
# H is the maximum number of clients that can be served

[m,n,t,H] = np.genfromtxt(fname = r'./Instances/data-100-10-4-3-0.txt', dtype = None, max_rows = 1)
f_values = np.genfromtxt(fname = r'./Instances/data-100-10-4-3-0.txt', dtype = None, max_rows = 4,skip_header=1)
c_values = np.genfromtxt(fname = r'./Instances/data-100-10-4-3-0.txt', dtype = None, skip_footer = 1,skip_header=5)
p_values = np.genfromtxt(fname = r'./Instances/data-100-10-4-3-0.txt', dtype = None, skip_header=405)


model.J = pyo.Set(initialize=[int(i)+1 for i in range(n)])
model.T= pyo.Set(initialize=[int(i)+1 for i in range(t)])
model.T.pprint()
model.I = pyo.Set(initialize=[int(i)+1 for i in range(m)])
model.H = pyo.Set(initialize=[int(i)+1 for i in range(H)])

# Generation of Subsets of all clients

client_list = [int(i)+1 for i in range(100)] 
list_H = [int(i)+1 for i in range(H)]
possible_groups_of_clients=[]
for i in list_H:
    possible_groups_of_clients += [list(elem) for elem in itertools.combinations(client_list,i)]

possible_groups_of_clients = possible_groups_of_clients[0:5] #Only select the first 5 subsets


model.K = pyo.Set(initialize=[int(i)+1 for i in range(len(possible_groups_of_clients))])

p_val = np.zeros((len(model.K),len(model.J),len(model.T))) 


for t in model.T: 
    t=t-1 #Pyomo starts at 1
    for j in model.J:
        j=j-1
        count = 0
        for k in possible_groups_of_clients:

            #k=k+1
            c_sum=0;
            for p in k:
                if t==0: 
                    c_sum = c_sum +c_values[p][j]
                elif t==1: 
                    c_sum = c_sum +c_values[p+100][j]
                elif t==2: 
                    c_sum = c_sum +c_values[p+200][j]
                elif t==3:
                    c_sum = c_sum +c_values[p+300][j]
            #print(f_values[t][j])


            p_val[count][j][t] = f_values[t][j]+ c_sum
            count=count+1


model.p_val = pyo.Param(model.K,model.J,model.T, initialize = lambda model,k,j,t: p_val[k-1][j-1][t-1])

#Matrice Aik 

A = [[0 for k in range(len(possible_groups_of_clients))]  for i in range(100)]
#model.p_val = pyo.Param(model.T,model.J,model.K, initialize = lambda model,t,j,k: A[t-1][j-1][k-1])
model.A = pyo.Param(model.I, model.K, mutable= True,initialize= lambda model,i,k: A[i-1][k-1])

count=1
for i in possible_groups_of_clients:

    for k in range(100):
        k=k+1
        #print(k)
        if k in i: 
            model.A[k,count]=1
        else: 
            model.A[k,count]=0

    count=count+1

model.z = pyo.Var(model.K,model.J,model.T,initialize= 0,within=pyo.NonNegativeReals,bounds=(0,1))



a=range(len(possible_groups_of_clients))
print(p_values)

# Minization of objective functions



# Constraint unique client
model.uniq_client = pyo.Constraint(
        model.I,
        rule=lambda model, i: sum(model.A[i,k]*model.z[k,j,t] for t in model.T for j in model.J for k in model.K) == 1
    )
model.unique_service_groupclients = pyo.Constraint(
       model.J, model.T,
        rule=lambda model,j,t: sum(model.z[k,j,t] for k in model.K)<=1
    )

model.min_factory_perperiod = pyo.Constraint(
        model.T,
        rule=lambda model, t: sum(model.z[k,j,t] for j in model.J for k in model.K )>=p_values[t-1]
    )



model.obj = pyo.Objective(rule= lambda model:sum(model.p_val[k,j,t]*model.z[k,j,t] for t in model.T  for j in model.J for k in model.K ), sense= pyo.minimize)
model.pprint()
```

## Constraint Group Client

```
sol = pyo.SolverFactory('glpk',).solve(model).write()

log_infeasible_constraints(model)


# ==========================================================
# = Solver Results                                         =
# ==========================================================
# ----------------------------------------------------------
#   Problem Information
# ----------------------------------------------------------
Problem: 
- Name: unknown
  Lower bound: -inf
  Upper bound: inf
  Number of objectives: 1
  Number of constraints: 145
  Number of variables: 201
  Number of nonzeros: 601
  Sense: minimize



# ----------------------------------------------------------
#   Solver Information
# ----------------------------------------------------------
Solver: 
- Status: ok
  Termination condition: infeasible
  Statistics: 
    Branch and bound: 
      Number of bounded subproblems: 0
      Number of created subproblems: 0
  Error rc: 0
  Time: 0.008042335510253906
ERROR: evaluating object as numeric value: z[1,1,1]
    (object: <class 'pyomo.core.base.var._GeneralVarData'>)
    No value for uninitialized NumericValue object z[1,1,1]
ERROR: evaluating object as numeric value: 1.0 - (A[1,1]*z[1,1,1] +
A[1,2]*z[2,1,1] + A[1,3]*z[3,1,1] + A[1,4]*z[4,1,1] + A[1,5]*z[5,1,1] +
A[1,1]*z[1,2,1] + A[1,2]*z[2,2,1] + A[1,3]*z[3,2,1] + A[1,4]*z[4,2,1] +
A[1,5]*z[5,2,1] + A[1,1]*z[1,3,1] + A[1,2]*z[2,3,1] + A[1,3]*z[3,3,1] +
A[1,4]*z[4,3,1] + A[1,5]*z[5,3,1] + A[1,1]*z[1,4,1] + A[1,2]*z[2,4,1] +
A[1,3]*z[3,4,1] + A[1,4]*z[4,4,1] + A[1,5]*z[5,4,1] + A[1,1]*z[1,5,1] +
A[1,2]*z[2,5,1] + A[1,3]*z[3,5,1] + A[1,4]*z[4,5,1] + A[1,5]*z[5,5,1] +
A[1,1]*z[1,6,1] + A[1,2]*z[2,6,1] + A[1,3]*z[3,6,1] + A[1,4]*z[4,6,1] +
A[1,5]*z[5,6,1] + A[1,1]*z[1,7,1] + A[1,2]*z[2,7,1] + A[1,3]*z[3,7,1] +
A[1,4]*z[4,7,1] + A[1,5]*z[5,7,1] + A[1,1]*z[1,8,1] + A[1,2]*z[2,8,1] +
A[1,3]*z[3,8,1] + A[1,4]*z[4,8,1] + A[1,5]*z[5,8,1] + A[1,1]*z[1,9,1] +
A[1,2]*z[2,9,1] + A[1,3]*z[3,9,1] + A[1,4]*z[4,9,1] + A[1,5]*z[5,9,1] +
A[1,1]*z[1,10,1] + A[1,2]*z[2,10,1] + A[1,3]*z[3,10,1] + A[1,4]*z[4,10,1]
+ A[1,5]*z[5,10,1] + A[1,1]*z[1,1,2] + A[1,2]*z[2,1,2] + A[1,3]*z[3,1,2] +
A[1,4]*z[4,1,2] + A[1,5]*z[5,1,2] + A[1,1]*z[1,2,2] + A[1,2]*z[2,2,2] +
A[1,3]*z[3,2,2] + A[1,4]*z[4,2,2] + A[1,5]*z[5,2,2] + A[1,1]*z[1,3,2] +
A[1,2]*z[2,3,2] + A[1,3]*z[3,3,2] + A[1,4]*z[4,3,2] + A[1,5]*z[5,3,2] +
A[1,1]*z[1,4,2] + A[1,2]*z[2,4,2] + A[1,3]*z[3,4,2] + A[1,4]*z[4,4,2] +
A[1,5]*z[5,4,2] + A[1,1]*z[1,5,2] + A[1,2]*z[2,5,2] + A[1,3]*z[3,5,2] +
A[1,4]*z[4,5,2] + A[1,5]*z[5,5,2] + A[1,1]*z[1,6,2] + A[1,2]*z[2,6,2] +
A[1,3]*z[3,6,2] + A[1,4]*z[4,6,2] + A[1,5]*z[5,6,2] + A[1,1]*z[1,7,2] +
A[1,2]*z[2,7,2] + A[1,3]*z[3,7,2] + A[1,4]*z[4,7,2] + A[1,5]*z[5,7,2] +
A[1,1]*z[1,8,2] + A[1,2]*z[2,8,2] + A[1,3]*z[3,8,2] + A[1,4]*z[4,8,2] +
A[1,5]*z[5,8,2] + A[1,1]*z[1,9,2] + A[1,2]*z[2,9,2] + A[1,3]*z[3,9,2] +
A[1,4]*z[4,9,2] + A[1,5]*z[5,9,2] + A[1,1]*z[1,10,2] + A[1,2]*z[2,10,2] +
A[1,3]*z[3,10,2] + A[1,4]*z[4,10,2] + A[1,5]*z[5,10,2] + A[1,1]*z[1,1,3] +
A[1,2]*z[2,1,3] + A[1,3]*z[3,1,3] + A[1,4]*z[4,1,3] + A[1,5]*z[5,1,3] +
A[1,1]*z[1,2,3] + A[1,2]*z[2,2,3] + A[1,3]*z[3,2,3] + A[1,4]*z[4,2,3] +
A[1,5]*z[5,2,3] + A[1,1]*z[1,3,3] + A[1,2]*z[2,3,3] + A[1,3]*z[3,3,3] +
A[1,4]*z[4,3,3] + A[1,5]*z[5,3,3] + A[1,1]*z[1,4,3] + A[1,2]*z[2,4,3] +
A[1,3]*z[3,4,3] + A[1,4]*z[4,4,3] + A[1,5]*z[5,4,3] + A[1,1]*z[1,5,3] +
A[1,2]*z[2,5,3] + A[1,3]*z[3,5,3] + A[1,4]*z[4,5,3] + A[1,5]*z[5,5,3] +
A[1,1]*z[1,6,3] + A[1,2]*z[2,6,3] + A[1,3]*z[3,6,3] + A[1,4]*z[4,6,3] +
A[1,5]*z[5,6,3] + A[1,1]*z[1,7,3] + A[1,2]*z[2,7,3] + A[1,3]*z[3,7,3] +
A[1,4]*z[4,7,3] + A[1,5]*z[5,7,3] + A[1,1]*z[1,8,3] + A[1,2]*z[2,8,3] +
A[1,3]*z[3,8,3] + A[1,4]*z[4,8,3] + A[1,5]*z[5,8,3] + A[1,1]*z[1,9,3] +
A[1,2]*z[2,9,3] + A[1,3]*z[3,9,3] + A[1,4]*z[4,9,3] + A[1,5]*z[5,9,3] +
A[1,1]*z[1,10,3] + A[1,2]*z[2,10,3] + A[1,3]*z[3,10,3] + A[1,4]*z[4,10,3]
+ A[1,5]*z[5,10,3] + A[1,1]*z[1,1,4] + A[1,2]*z[2,1,4] + A[1,3]*z[3,1,4] +
A[1,4]*z[4,1,4] + A[1,5]*z[5,1,4] + A[1,1]*z[1,2,4] + A[1,2]*z[2,2,4] +
A[1,3]*z[3,2,4] + A[1,4]*z[4,2,4] + A[1,5]*z[5,2,4] + A[1,1]*z[1,3,4] +
A[1,2]*z[2,3,4] + A[1,3]*z[3,3,4] + A[1,4]*z[4,3,4] + A[1,5]*z[5,3,4] +
A[1,1]*z[1,4,4] + A[1,2]*z[2,4,4] + A[1,3]*z[3,4,4] + A[1,4]*z[4,4,4] +
A[1,5]*z[5,4,4] + A[1,1]*z[1,5,4] + A[1,2]*z[2,5,4] + A[1,3]*z[3,5,4] +
A[1,4]*z[4,5,4] + A[1,5]*z[5,5,4] + A[1,1]*z[1,6,4] + A[1,2]*z[2,6,4] +
A[1,3]*z[3,6,4] + A[1,4]*z[4,6,4] + A[1,5]*z[5,6,4] + A[1,1]*z[1,7,4] +
A[1,2]*z[2,7,4] + A[1,3]*z[3,7,4] + A[1,4]*z[4,7,4] + A[1,5]*z[5,7,4] +
A[1,1]*z[1,8,4] + A[1,2]*z[2,8,4] + A[1,3]*z[3,8,4] + A[1,4]*z[4,8,4] +
A[1,5]*z[5,8,4] + A[1,1]*z[1,9,4] + A[1,2]*z[2,9,4] + A[1,3]*z[3,9,4] +
A[1,4]*z[4,9,4] + A[1,5]*z[5,9,4] + A[1,1]*z[1,10,4] + A[1,2]*z[2,10,4] +
A[1,3]*z[3,10,4] + A[1,4]*z[4,10,4] + A[1,5]*z[5,10,4])
        (object: <class 'pyomo.core.expr.numeric_expr.SumExpression'>)
    No value for uninitialized NumericValue object z[1,1,1]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 246, in <module>
    log_infeasible_constraints(model)
  File "/home/john/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyomo   /util/infeasible.py", line 25, in log_infeasible_constraints
    if constr.equality and fabs(value(constr.lower - constr.body)) >= tol:
  File "/home/john/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyomo/core/expr/numvalue.py", line 226, in value
    tmp = obj(exception=True)
  File "/home/john/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyomo/core/expr/numeric_expr.py", line 222, in __call__
    return evaluate_expression(self, exception)
  File "/home/john/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyomo/core/expr/visitor.py", line 973, in evaluate_expression
    return visitor.dfs_postorder_stack(exp)
  File "/home/john/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyomo/core/expr/visitor.py", line 518, in dfs_postorder_stack
flag, value = self.visiting_potential_leaf(_sub)
  File "/home/john/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyomo/core/expr/visitor.py", line 893, in visiting_potential_leaf
    return True, value(node)
  File "/home/john/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyomo/core/expr/numvalue.py", line 230, in value
% (obj.name,))
ValueError: No value for uninitialized NumericValue object z[1,1,1]
```

I got this error whatever I try and I don't understand why Z should be initialized as it is the variable I'm trying to minimize

Comment: Hi Adam, it's a bit tough to debug this at the moment because we can't run your code (we don't have the data files). Further, the code is quite long at the moment. Could you work to update your example to cut away any unnecessary code and also to be fully self-contained (so we can run it)? Perhaps you could construct a very small example that still gives this error.

Comment: Hi Adam. Your code is hard to debug right now and I strongly suggest following @josliber 's advices. But since it is usually hard to find what we want to ask in a Pyomo question, I understand that investigation has to be made. First of all, it seems like your problem is infeasible and your solver did not assign a numeric value to your variables before you tried to retrieve the value of `z`. Try to show us what happens if you do `model.z.display()` right before and right after the `solve` command and edit your question to include those results. We want to eliminate any false diagnostic here.